# java-error in null pointer exception

Tags: class, pointers, object, linked-list

PLEASE HELP ME TO FIND THIS ANSWER
NULL POINTER EXCEPTION ERROR HELP ME

on these two lines

25,83
null pointer exception please correct my code
i created a object l with reference to class linkk
to access methods in the class
but while accessing the methods in the class with different conditions 
it is showing null pointer exception
i didnt finish the code due to this error im struck at this point i cant move 
further
this is my post 
in overflow
i have read answers in overflow but this is the 
first time fr me to post a question in overflow ,
today i created a ac nd posting this question please help me frnds

```js
import    java . util.Scanner;



class node
{
    int i,q; 
     node next;
     node prev;
}

class link{
    public static void main(String args[])
{
     linkk l = new linkk();
     
  l.op();
     int user=0;   
     while(user!=10)
    {Scanner a=new Scanner(System.in);
      if(user==1)
      {
       System.out.println("\nenter data\n");
       
       l.create(a.nextInt());
     
      }System.out.println("\n1.create link\n2.insert beginning\n3.insert middle\n4.insert end\n5.delete data\n6.reverse");
user=a.nextInt();
}
if(user==2)
l.insertbeg();
if(user==3)
 l.insertmid();
if(user==4)
 l.insertend();
if(user==5)
 l.del();
if(user==6)
 l.reverse();
if(user==7)
l.display();
  
 }

}

class  linkk
{  
node temp4;
int ch,add,cnt=0,t=0,b;
node p= new node();
node q;
 node last;
node first=null;

public boolean isEmpty()

{

    return first == null;

}

public  void insertbeg()
{
}

public  void insertmid()
{
}
public void insertend()
{
}
public  void del()
{
} 
public  void reverse()
{
}
public  void display()
{
}
public  void create(int val)
{   
  first.i=val;

  first.next=null;
  cnt++;   
        }
 public void ob()
 {
 }
 public void op()
 {
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your defined first as null as `node first=null;` and you are trying to access i with first object using `first.i=val;` by calling `l.create(a.nextInt());`.

You should initialize first as below:

```
node first = new node();//and then access i of it and so on.
```

Comment: frnd really thank u the code worked thanks fr spending ur time